# VB 2008 - Populate combobox from CSV file

Tags: csv, combobox

I am writing a simple application which I'm planning to use in a work environment. I have managed to find the answers to the majority of my queries so far, but this one eludes me.
I'm hoping someone can assist me.

I have a CSV file with 3 columns in it ("PCName","IPAddress","Location"). The CSV file is in the same format throughout with no header row.

What I want to do is to read in just the items up until the first , and then when this is selected to use the corresponding IP address in column 2 to initiate an RDP connection to the PC.

I have the code behind the scenes to initiate the RDP, just seem to have hit a brick wall with this element. I found the following code, but it doesn't do what I'm after:
        ComboBox1.DataSource = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\test.csv")
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
        ComboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
        ComboBox1.Text = "Select an item"

Can anyone assist me in progressing this at all?
Even if someone can just assist me in getting the first column in the combo box and then based on the selection to populate a text box, I should be able to figure the rest out from there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have managed to resolve the importing into the combobox, however I'm now trying to update a textbox with the corresponding value from the row in question.

E.g. If you select A then the textbox updates with 1, if you select B the text box updates with 2, etc etc.

The format of my file (will always be the same) will be:
A,1,A1234
B,2,B0987
C,3,L8888
etc.

I'm intending to create a list of servers with the first item being the server name (which you select), the second item is the servers unique identifier, and the third item is the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

'Resolved using the following:

```
   Dim ServName = (From line In IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\Testing\Servers.csv") _
```

Where line.Length > 0 _
Let Items = line.Split(","c) _
Select New With _
    {.ServerRef = Items(0), _
      .ServerName = Items(1), _
      .ServerIP = Items(2) _
    } _
 ).ToList

```
    For Each Server In ServName
        Console.WriteLine("[{0} [{1}] [{2}]", _
                          Server.ServerRef, _
                          Server.ServerName, _
                          Server.ServerIP _
              )
    Next

    Dim h As String
    h = 0
    For Each Server In ServName
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerRef)
        ComboBox2.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerName)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(Server(h).ServerIP)

        h = h + 1
    Next
```